# Using cocoapods framework in a framework - image not found

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I am trying to create a framework in which I would like to use another framework from Cocoapods (SwiftWebSocket). The code compiles however when I run my app I get the infamous:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: 
@rpath/SwiftWebSocket.framework/Versions/A/SwiftWebSocket
  Referenced from: /Users/xxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestFx-efmkyfxootekawemcuqasuakdyii/Build/Products/Debug/TestFx.framework/Versions/A/TestFx
Reason: image not found
```

When I dump the shared libraries with `otool -L` I see:

```
TestFx:
    @rpath/TestFx.framework/Versions/A/TestFx (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    @rpath/SwiftWebSocket.framework/Versions/A/SwiftWebSocket (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
...
```

The problem seems to be that the path to SwiftWebSocket is `@rpath/SwiftWebSocket.framework/...` however on disk the SwiftWebSocket.framework is actually inside a SwiftWebSocket directory:

```
├── Pods_TestFx.framework
├── SwiftWebSocket
│   └── SwiftWebSocket.framework
├── TestFx.framework
├── TestFxApp.app
```

If I create a link to SwiftWebSocket.framework in the parent directory then the framework can be found and application starts.

How do I tell xcode/cocoapads that the path to look for the SwiftWebSocket framework embedded in my framework should be `@rpath/SwiftWebSocket/SwiftWebSocket.framework/...` and not the `@rpath/SwiftWebSocket.framework/...` or in general make it work in any way?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your **podspec** (in your framework)

`spec.framework    = 'SwiftWebSocket'`

-

You can find more info on how to configure your podspec here:
https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried doing this but unfortunately it did not fix the issue.

Comment: @Pawel can you please post how your .podspec looks like?

Comment: I think I figured this out. the .podspec file is not needed - I was only consuming the library. The issue was that I created the Podfile manually and omitted the apps completely because they did not have any cocoapod dependencies. Apparently this caused the issue. Once I created the Podfile with `pod init` and left entries for the apps I no longer see the issue. Thanks for trying to help!